# Clean,Trim-VBA errors (removed filtered data, leaves #NA, does not work on big data)

Tags: excel, vba, data-cleaning

I have used this VBA below with success to clean and trim exported data.

I have started to see 3 problems.

1. I have started to use it on data formatted as tables and when the table
   is filtered the script removes rows. Should I add a portion to the
   Script that removes any filter in the list first or is it another
   way?
2. Another issue is that it ends if the data amount is huge. Do you see
   any errors that I have missed in the Script?
3. The third issue I have notices is that many #Value or #NA pops up in the data. Can this be avoided?

```
Sub CallCleanTrimExcel()
    Dim MasterFile As Workbook

    Dim SurveyRptName As String
    Dim SurveyReport As Workbook

    Set MasterFile = ThisWorkbook '

    SurveyRptName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xlsx), *xlsx", 1, _
        "Please select the data you want to cleanse.", , False)
    If SurveyRptName <> "False" Then
        Set SurveyReport = Workbooks.Open(SurveyRptName)
    End If

    SurveyReport.Activate

Dim rng As Range
Dim Area As Range
Dim rngTemp As Range

Set rngTemp = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
If Not rngTemp Is Nothing Then
    Range(Cells(1, 1), rngTemp).Select
End If

    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim m As Double
    Dim n As Double

    arr = Selection.Value

    For m = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For n = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            arr(m, n) = CleanTrimExcel(arr(m, n))
        Next n
    Next m

    Selection = arr()

ActiveSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"

MsgBox "Cleaning done!"

End Sub
```

```
Function CleanTrimExcel(ByVal S As String, Optional ConvertNonBreakingSpace As Boolean = True) As String

    Dim X As Long
    Dim CodesToReplace() As Variant

    If ConvertNonBreakingSpace Then
        ReDim CodesToReplace(1 To 7)
        CodesToReplace = Array(127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157, 160)
    Else
        ReDim CodesToReplace(1 To 6)
        CodesToReplace = Array(127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157)
    End If

    For X = LBound(CodesToReplace) To UBound(CodesToReplace)
        If InStr(S, Chr(CodesToReplace(X))) Then S = Replace(S, Chr(CodesToReplace(X)), Chr(0))
    Next

    CleanTrimExcel = WorksheetFunction.Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(S))

End Function
```

Comment: Your code `Set rngTemp = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)` seems odd. You search `xlPrevious` but you don't instruct where to start. If your intention is to find the last used row consider `Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(XlUp)`. Your clear in `If Not rngTemp Is Nothing Then` but seem to forget that the program will execute the next instruction if the condition isn't met. This omission is repeated elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I'm gonna start with your first question: you can either clear the filter or use `SpecialCells` to work with filtered cells. Also, your code presumes that the user will always select a file to open (which you are using to set `SurveyReport`). If the user doesn't chose a file, your code will continue and most probably throw an error. I would suggest that if a file is not selected, exit the function

Comment: Can you give an example (before and after) of a string that's been cleaned that becomes `#VALUE` or `#NA` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice. I think I was able to fix the errors. The third error I have not been able to replicate so maybe the data was corrupt from the start.

Now this Script should not replace any data. :-)

```
Sub CallCleanTrimExcel()
    Dim MasterFile As Workbook

    Dim SurveyRptName As String
    Dim SurveyReport As Workbook

    Set MasterFile = ThisWorkbook '

    SurveyRptName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xlsx), *xlsx", 1, _
        "Please select the data you want to cleanse.", , False)
    If SurveyRptName <> "False" Then
        Set SurveyReport = Workbooks.Open(SurveyRptName)
    End If
If SurveyRptName = "False" Then
MsgBox ("No file selected.")
Exit Sub
End If

    SurveyReport.Activate

If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
  ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If

Dim rng As Range
Dim Area As Range
Dim rngTemp As Range

Range("a1", Cells(Range("a1000000").End(xlUp).Row, Range("xfd1").End(xlToLeft).Column)).Select
Set rngTemp = Selection

If Not rngTemp Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "Data found! Cleaning will now start. It can take a while. Don't worry if Excel gets blank."
End If

    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim m As Double
    Dim n As Double

    arr = Selection.Value

    For m = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For n = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            arr(m, n) = CleanTrimExcel(arr(m, n))
        Next n
    Next m

    Selection = arr()

ActiveSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection.CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = "Data_table"

MsgBox "Cleaning done!"

End Sub
```

```
Function CleanTrimExcel(ByVal S As String, Optional ConvertNonBreakingSpace As Boolean = True) As String

    Dim X As Long
    Dim CodesToReplace() As Variant

    If ConvertNonBreakingSpace Then
        ReDim CodesToReplace(1 To 7)
        CodesToReplace = Array(127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157, 160)
    Else
        ReDim CodesToReplace(1 To 6)
        CodesToReplace = Array(127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157)
    End If

    For X = LBound(CodesToReplace) To UBound(CodesToReplace)
        If InStr(S, Chr(CodesToReplace(X))) Then S = Replace(S, Chr(CodesToReplace(X)), Chr(0))
    Next

    CleanTrimExcel = WorksheetFunction.Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(S))

End Function
```